# Time series: Having trouble with model fitting

Tags: python, time-series, arima, model-fitting

I have been trying to practice time series fundamentals. However, I am having trouble with model fitting.

```
#here is the model --> I started with a basic AR model
#AR Model
#order=(2,1,0)
```

```
    model = ARIMA(Data_logScaled, order=(0,1,2))
    results_MA = model.fit()
    plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
    plt.plot(results_MA.fittedvalues, color='red')
    plt.title('RSS: %.4f'%sum((results_MA.fittedvalues - datasetLogDiffShifting['#Passengers'])**2))
    print('Plotting MA model')
```

The notebook i had been following used:

```
results_AR = model.fit(disp=-1).
```

but I kept getting the unexpected parameter error.

```
#Data_logScaled --> np.log(data)
#datasetLogDiffShifting --> datasetLogDiffShifting = Data_logScaled - Data_logScaled.shift()
```

I am still a begginer so kindly help me out, thanks!
This is supposed to be the graph:
[image]

But my graph is like this:
[image]